# Trigonometric functions in JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I don't understand, why I get some very strange values from trigonometric functions in JavaScript. For example:

```
Math.sin(Math.PI); // returns 1.2246467991473532e-16, but should return 0
Math.cos(Math.PI/2); // returns 6.123233995736766e-17, but should return 0
Math.sin(3.14); // returns 0.0015926529164868282, whitch is ok but
Math.sin(3.141592); // returns 6.535897930762419e-7!
```

I tried this in Mozilla and Chrome and got the same result. It seems the parameter of the trigonometric function is too precise.

Please help!

Comment: 1.22e-16 is VERY close to zero: it is 0.000000000000000122 to be precise. Since Math.PI is not a perfect representation of PI, as PI is infinite and cannot be contained in any variable, you're always going to get an approximation.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the e-16 so i thought the answer was wrong. Thank you @Darkerlvy

Comment: No problem. The bottom line is that floating points are very accurate - so accurate that they can even show their own lack of perfection.

Comment: To put the error into context, its like measuring the circumference of the earth and getting it wrong by by less than the size of an atom

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Number.EPSILON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON)

> The `Number.EPSILON` property represents the difference between 1 and the smallest floating point number greater than 1.

and take the absolute delta of the value and wanted value and check if it is smaller than the `Number.EPSILON`. If `true`, then the value's error is smaller than the possible error of floating point arithmetic.

```js
console.log([
    [Math.sin(Math.PI), 0], 
    [Math.cos(Math.PI/2), 0],
    [Math.sin(3.14), 0.0015926529164868282],
    [Math.sin(3.141592), 6.535897930762419e-7]
].map(([a, b]) => Math.abs(a - b) < Number.EPSILON));
```

Some more to read about the problem with limited digital representation of floating point values:

- [Does “epsilon” really guarantees anything in floating-point computations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729637/does-epsilon-really-guarantees-anything-in-floating-point-computations)
- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)